# Giving notice at the end of the year

Tags: notice-period

So with my company there are many benefits that begin on January 1 and go thru December 31... Profit sharing and bonus. The question I have is... If I give my notice and the last day falls on the weekend, they will more than likely not give me my profit sharing and none of the bonus even though I worked the entire year with the exception of the 31st of December because it happens to fall on a Saturday...

Should I tell my new job I can't start until January 9th, just to be sure that I still get the perks from my old job? It is a substantial amount I will be losing out on $13k since my new job will not be offering a sign on bonus to start.

Answer (score 5):

To maximize your chances of getting these year end perks, you should not submit your notice until after you receive them.

Answer (score 4):

Any time you give notice at a job, you have to be prepared to have it end immediately. Notice is a courtesy and not something they have to respect. Depending on what you do, many companies routinely ignore notices and end the employment for security reasons as well.

In other words, the only thing you can count on are the days that you're still telling them you're employed. If they see a financial benefit to letting you go immediately, they likely will.